# What's the mesorah-tradition tag for?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The [mesorah-tradition](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesorah-tradition) tag currently has 79 questions that have not been closed. Most of those concern general Jewish traditions, *m'sora*, one receives from his forebears or teachers. A few, however, concern the *m'sora*: the tradition of spellings, vowels, cantillation, etc., on *Tanach*. (Those are [11290](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11290), [11295](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11295), [14671](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14671), [25884](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25884), [33566](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33566), [34342](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34342), [34806](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34806), [37311](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37311), and [48256](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48256), though I may have missed some.) Which should the tag be used for? or both, as it is now?

Comment: In my opinion these are both tagworthy topics. They are also not the same thing, so I think there should be two separate tags.

Comment: @WAF, perhaps post an answer to that effect so that people might up- and downvote it.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative proposal:

[mesorah-ancestral-tradition](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesorah-ancestral-tradition)

and

[mesorah-scribal-tradition](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesorah-scribal-tradition)

I think the latter is more specific and immediately understandable to the uninitiated than either [mesorah-masoretic-tradition](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesorah-masoretic-tradition) and [mesorah-of-tanach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesorah-of-tanach).

Answer (score 2):

Since these are two tagworthy topics that are distinct but synonyms, they should be split into two different tags:

- [mesorah-ancestral-tradition](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesorah-ancestral-tradition) and
- [mesorah-masoretic-tradition](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesorah-masoretic-tradition)

There's gotta be a better name for the second tag, though. I'd appreciate a counter-answer to that effect.

Comment: [tag:scribal-tradition]? [tag:textual-tradition]? [tag:canonical-tradition]?

Comment: I'm working on a wording for the second tag....do we need the word "mesorah" in the tag at all? [ancestral-tradition] sounds fine to me.....

Comment: my thought is that otherwise people will make a mistake when they mean mesoretic-tradition.... but i think those are spelled close enough that it's not a big deal.

Comment: To clarify: I was suggesting [ancestral-tradition] for the first tag, not the second. ....I don't have any good ideas for wordings, yet.

Comment: FYI, I've followed up with another answer here.

Comment: @msh210 As have I, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

As a tweak to [Charles Koppelman's answer](/a/3341) (as he requested therein), I'd like to suggest we split it into [mesorah-ancestral-tradition](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesorah-ancestral-tradition) and [mesorah-of-tanach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesorah-of-tanach).