# Can I ask for explanation about a Masoretic note?

Tags: support, scope

There is a Masoretic note in my Hebrew Bible (in the Masorah Parva/Qetana) that I don't understand. I think I know what it means, literally, but I don't see how it applies to the marked word. Can I ask for clarification on this site?

There is a [mesorah-tradition](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesorah-tradition) tag, but it does not seem to be about the Masoretic notes, at least not primarily so
([What's the mesorah-tradition tag for?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3338/24663)). I have seen [What topics are in- and out-of-scope on Mi Yodeya?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1473), but I'm unsure whether this question would fall under "a Jewish text" / "general knowledge as it relates directly to Judaism" (both OK) or "Hebrew language" (not OK) or something else still.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my view, a question like this should be a good fit here. It certainly seems to me that (at the very least) it would fall under "a Jewish text (explaining a passage)".

Comment: Thanks! I have asked the question here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/119513/24663.